# I can’t update user setting “When a cloud recording is available” option using Zoom API and there are no error message sent back

Tags: zoom-sdk

**Description**

I sent a patch request to update Zoom user setting ( enable “Meeting”/“Email Notification”/“When a cloud recording is available”). It only returned an empty string and “When a cloud recording is available” setting didn’t change status. Even though I can change that setting option on the account just fine. What is the problem here? And how to fix it?

**Error**

The request only return an empty string.

**App Type**

I’m using my company’s own platform. It does all the Zoom authentication in background, I only provide the API path and request body.

**Endpoint**

PATCH
/users/{userId}/settings

**Steps to reproduce the behavior**:

1. Request URL: /users/{userId}/settings
   Header: { method: “PATCH” }
   Body: { “email_notification”: { “cloud_recording_available_reminder”: true }}
2. An empty string was returned. The setting option didn’t change.

**Additional context**

Unfortunately I don’t know much about the internal process of our company’s platform, so I can not show a log file here. But I tried getting user settings ( GET /users/{userId}/settings) and updating the same option on account settings ( PATCH /accounts/{accountId}/settings) just fine. Other setting options of user can be updated too, just “Meeting”/“Email Notification”/“When a cloud recording is available” option that has problem.

I have found some similar questions on this site and Zoom devforum, but it seems like they only used the wrong api endpoint or made a typo in json body. In my case the endpoint is correct (as mentioned above, I have successfully updated other user setting options), and my json body is correct too (successfully updated the same option on account settings).

Comment: Apparently it's a bug. [Zoom devforum](https://devforum.zoom.us/t/i-cant-update-user-setting-when-a-cloud-recording-is-available-option-and-there-are-no-error-message-sent-back/57006/4?u=koklok)